# Regex and Powershell that gets only data between a pre set number of slashes

Tags: regex, powershell, awk, slash

Imagine I have a line like that below:

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/
```

I need to get the data between the 2nd and 5th slash, but would like to control this selection regularly in between the code.

This way the substring for the 2nd and 5th would be `/b/c/d/`

So I've tried: `$ cat test.txt | gawk '/\/{2}(.*?)\/{5}/{print $0}'` without success. I need a working code line for both regex and powershell.

Comment: See a [sed](https://ideone.com/lGP6Sy) solution.  It should be easy to convert to PS for use with `-replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PowerShell, `-replace` can perform the job. `-replace` operator uses regex for its matching mechanism.

```
'/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/' -replace "(/[^/]+){1}((/[^/]+){3}/).*",'$2'
```

`-split` and `-join` can also perform the job.

```
"/{0}/" -f (('/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/' -split "/")[2..4] -join "/")
```

For a straight PowerShell regex match, you can use the following:

```
([regex]"(?<=(/[^/]+){1})(/[^/]+){3}/").Match('/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/').Value
```

Any of the above techniques can take input from a variable or reading a file as shown below:

```
# Using a variable
$str = '/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/'
$str -replace "(/[^/]+){1}((/[^/]+){3}/).*",'$2'
/b/c/d/

# Reading from a file
([regex]"(?<=(/[^/]+){1})(/[^/]+){3}/").Match((Get-Content File.txt)).Value
/b/c/d/
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(written and tested with provided samples only).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{for(i=3;i<=5;i++){val=(val?val OFS:"")$i};print OFS val;val=""}'  Input_file
```

With GNU `awk`'s `gensub` approach one could try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{regex="/([a-zA-Z]+)/(([a-zA-Z]/){3}).*"} {print gensub(regex, "/\\2", "1",$0)}' Input_file
```

---

---

***MORE Generic:*** Change min and max value and get output as per need.

```
awk -v min=2 -v max="5" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="/"
  regex="^/(([a-zA-Z]/+){"(max-1)"}).*"
}
{
  val=gensub(regex, "/\\1", "1",$0)
  num=split(val,array,"/")
  for(i=min+1;i<=(num-1);i++){
    value=(value?value:"")OFS array[i]
  }
  print value
  value=""
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder, this returns me a "b/c/d"

Comment: @Mensch, sure, fixed it now, please check and let me know now?

Comment: Dear Ravinder, thanks again. So it looks like it is impossible to do it for a single command line in regex, correct ? Wouldn't you know how to solve this with powersheel ?

Comment: @Mensch, please check my EDIT solution with `gensub` of  GNU `awk` and let me know then it uses regex approach.